# iOS changing switching views

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

when click Audio button in  view1.xib

i want to load view2.xib file (this is not in uiwebview)

I want in my application just like [this link](http://fuelyourcoding.com/iphone-view-switching-tutorial/comment-page-1/#comment-8987).

But in this link the `rootviewcontroller` is in `uiview` but in my application the root view controller in `UIWebView` how to change the view if the `rootview` is in `uiwebview`?

Comment: Do you mean that the rootviewcontroller contains a UIWebView? please can you provide more info?

Comment: If you want to change UIWebView content then it's easy! just create another html page and call that page. Another HTML page is your second view - COMMENTED AFTER GETTING 5% OF UNDERSTANDING OF WHAT HAS BEEN ASK so pardon my comment

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith yes root view controller contain UIWebView .. thanks for your interest...

Comment: Do you mean that the rootview controller will not have any button, does it have only links? do you want a link from inside the uiwebview to take you to the next view?

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith YES. but in the next view (second view) i have buttons..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the uiwebview html content for navigating to another view, you do have a link
for example

```
<a href="TEST://GOTOVIEW">Go To Second View</a>
```

In the viewcontroller that contains the UIWebView, set the delegate of webView to be the the viewcontroller

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
   webView.delegate = self;
}
```

in the view controller Implement following

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {

        NSString *urlAbsolute = [request.URL absoluteString];
        if ([urlAbsolute isEqualToString:@"TEST://GOTOVIEW"])
        {
            //Go to the second view by calling the switchPage function
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: i want to load uiwebview from new .xib file when i click a button in uiwebview ..

Comment: Then go to View2.xib and add a uiwebview to it

Comment: when click the html button in view1.xib i want to load view2.xib(this .xib page is uiview not  in uiwebview)  in your code you are mention @"TEST://GOTOVIEW" instead that i want to load .xib file there.. is it possible..

Comment: I dont really understand your question, let me try to get it, so you have view1.xib and view2.xib, view1.xib will have  uiwebview, that contains a web page, this web page will have a link, and when user clicks on the link it will take him to the view2.xib? and view2.xib will also have a webpage? is that correct? please provide me additional info, or code that i could help you with :)

Comment: view2.xib doesnot have webpage it is  in uiview.. other than this your understanding is correct...

Comment: view2.xib is a uiview and not a uiviewcontroller?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12032/discussion-between-omar-abdelhafith-and-bharathi-d)